# One network that classifies three classes or two networks that do binary classifications?

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing

I've been training a fully convolutional network for semantic segmentation, more particularly a U-net, to classify three things in an image: object_type1, object_type2, and background. However, I've found better results by having two networks that do binary classification. The first network classifying just the background and object_type1 and the other network classifying the background and object_type2.

Then, I can combine the results using old school techniques.

My question then becomes, is this a common practice - to have two networks do the work instead of just one? Does binary classification commonly provide better results than ternary classification?

If the answer to the first question is no, then is it considered bad practice to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely **not a bad practice**.

In some context (imbalanced labels or non-contradictory labels, e.g.), it can be much easier to cut a multi-class classification problem into multiple problems.

However, in your case, a possible improvment of your setup could be to share part of the architecture and the weights of your neural networks as they apply to the same images (as far as I understood). 
This way, the learning of one task could benefit from the other task.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense, especially with regards to knowing the difference between background and foreground. But how exactly do I figure out which layers/weights to share and how exactly would I do so? Could you possible link some resource for that in your answer? That would be very helpful.

Comment: For the moment, I do not have particular papers in mind... However, it is a very common thing to take a pretrained computer-vision model (such as VGG, resnet, inception-net, etc.) to cut off (at least) the last layer (the softmax one) and to fine-tune it to adapt to new output categories.

Comment: Also there is this paper by google brain where they create one model for multiple (quite diverse) tasks: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05137
Maybe you will find here too